# call to WCF service from angularjs returns -1

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am using following code to call WCF service from angularjs. This function will be called on change of a textbox. 
HTML code :

```
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search for items" id="textFiled" class="input" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-keyup="checkKeyUp($event)" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()" /></div>
```

javascript code

```
//Function To Call On ng-change
    $rootScope.search = function () {
        var searchTextSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($scope.searchText);
        if (searchTextSmallLetters.length > 2) {

            $http({
                method: "GET",
                withCredentials: true,
                url: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:XX/Service.svc/Clients?prefix=" + searchTextSmallLetters,
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    alert('success');
                }
                else {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert(response.status);
                alert('fail');
            });
        }
};
```

WCF operation contract for the service :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "/Clients?prefix={prefix}")]
List<string> GetClients(string prefix);
```

Function fails by giving alert message with status code "-1". When i check the same call in fiddler its returning the searched clients, with status code 200.

Hope someone can help me with this. Any suggestions or comments will be great. Thank you.

Comment: WCF is hosted on same domain as calling angularjs code.

Comment: then why would you put `http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:XX` in the url - you'd just use the path - disregard my CORS suggestion

Comment: tried your suggestion, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, in past I got similar behavior (-1 status code) from js when:

- I was making cross domain calls and the OPTIONS call was failing. The framework used was not able to properly process the non 200 result. From https to http or http(s) with different port could cause this, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control. I would look over in the Chrome's developer console to see what calls are made and what was the result (without using Fiddler!)
- debugging using Fiddler and making https calls